# How Are Registers X/Y/ZMM16-31 Encoded?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, disassembly, machine-code, avx512

As I understand, since AVX, trough the 3-Byte VEX or EVEX prefix, you can encode up to 32 XMM/YMM/ZMM registers in 64-bit mode, but when looking trough the Intel manual past the fact that it tells you that is possible, I cannot find the part where it explains how that actually occurs. There is only one extension field that I can see, which is the REX inverted fields, but not anything else, aside from a special place in the EVEX prefix to encode mask registers.

You would need 2 bits somewhere to encode that many registers. Do you have to combine 2 of the inverted REX fields inside the VEX/EVEX prefixes somehow, or how does this process work?

Comment: xmm16..31 (and their ymm/zmm equivalents) are new with AVX-512 and only accessible via EVEX prefixes, which have 2 extra bits to add to ModRM, and a 5-bit extra field.

Comment: @PeterCordes Are you refering to this?:`EVEX.RXBNext-8 register specifier modifierP[7 : 5]Combine with ModR/M.reg, ModR/M.rm (base, index/vidx).`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

xmm16..31 (and their ymm/zmm equivalents) are **new with AVX-512 and only accessible via EVEX prefixes**, which have **2** extra bits to add to each of the ModRM fields, and a 5 more bits as an extra field for the third operand.

REX + legacy-SSE, and VEX for AVX1/2 encodings, can only access xmm/ymm0..15.

[Wikipedia's EVEX article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EVEX_prefix) has a pretty good table that shows where the bits come from, which I transcribed some of:

| Addr mode | Bit 4 | Bit 3 | Bits [2:0] | Register type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| REG | EVEX.R' | EVEX.R | ModRM.reg | General Purpose, Vector |
| RM | EVEX.X | EVEX.B | ModRM.r/m | GPR, Vector |
| NDS/NDD | EVEX.V' | EVEX.v3 | EVEX.v2v1v0 | Vector |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| Base | 0 | EVEX.B | SIB.base (or modrm) | GPR |
| Index | 0 | EVEX.X | SIB.index | GPR |

If the R/M operand is a vector register instead of a memory addressing mode, it uses *both* the X (index) and B (base) bits as extra register-number bits.  Because that means there's no SIB.index field which could also need extension to select r8..r15.

---

In REX and VEX prefixes, The X bit goes unused when the source operand isn't memory with an indexed addressing mode.  (https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#REX_prefix, but note in a register-number table earlier in that page showing *X.Reg*, [X is just a placeholder for R or B, not REX.X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300321/what-is-the-x-part-of-the-encoding-of-the-r8-15-registers); confusing choice on that page).

See also [x86 BSWAP instruction REX doesn't follow Intel specs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484556/x86-bswap-instruction-rex-doesnt-follow-intel-specs) for another diagram of using an extra register-number bit from a REX prefix.

Comment: Thanks, man. I get it now, which fields are used for extension depends on the instruction used

Comment: @CarolVictor See also the table at https://euroassembler.eu/easource/ii.htm#IiAssembleAVX to understand how the five bits of base&index registers are sparsed among prefix + ModR/M + SIB.